# How do I start a public stream with Steam Broadcasting?

Tags: steam, streaming, steam-broadcasting

I know that Steam Broadcasting is primarily made for friends requesting to view other friends playing games, but there is also a public streaming section.

I know that Steam broadcasting normally works by someone requesting to watch you play, and Steam then beginning to stream.

But that doesn't really help me in starting a public stream, since I want to set the stream up before other people start watching.

So far I haven't found an explicit "Start a public stream" button or anything, so how do I start a public stream with Steam Broadcaster?

Comment: Watch the stream on another computer (or in the background of your game) so the stream is open.

Answer (score 5):

To my knowledge, you can't explicitly start streaming.

What you *can* do is set your security settings so that the public can view your streams.

It appears to make the stream show up in the public section as I've had random people start my stream before when I was playing La Mulana.

[image: Steam Broadcasting settings]

Comment: As an alternative, clicking the Not Broadcasting link will open the stream page and force your own client to join your stream...